# java.util.Calendar WEEK_OF_YEAR gives 1 for 365 & 366th days

Tags: java

Trying to find Week-of-year for a given date. 
Using the below piece of code. [ Java 1.7 ]

Problem: 
29-Dec-2012 = week 52
30-Dec-2012 = week 1
30-Dec-2013 = week 52
31-Dec-2013 = week 1

When day-of-year = 365 or 366 , it gives week-of-year to 1. 
Looks like some modulo 52 happens.
How to fix this ?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class cal2{
   public static void main (String[] args) {

   Calendar mycal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();  

   mycal.setLenient(false);

   int year  = 2012;
   int month = 11;  //0=Jan, 11=Dec
   int date  = 29; 

   mycal.set(year , 0 , 1);
   mycal.setFirstDayOfWeek(mycal.get(mycal.DAY_OF_WEEK));

   mycal.set(year,month,date);
   System.out.println("\n>>>>>>>>WEEK :"+mycal.get(mycal.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

   // System.out.println("\nDATE :"+mycal);

   }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

[**SEE HERE**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)  from Docs

First Week

> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two
>   parameters: the first day of the week and the minimal days in first
>   week (from 1 to 7). These numbers are taken from the locale resource
>   data when a Calendar is constructed. They may also be specified
>   explicitly through the methods for setting their values.
>
> When setting or getting the WEEK_OF_MONTH or WEEK_OF_YEAR fields,
>   Calendar must determine the first week of the month or year as a
>   reference point. The first week of a month or year is defined as the
>   earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and
>   containing at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days of that month or
>   year. Weeks numbered ..., -1, 0 precede the first week; weeks numbered
>   2, 3,... follow it. Note that the normalized numbering returned by
>   get() may be different. For example, a specific Calendar subclass may
>   designate the week before week 1 of a year as week n of the previous
>   year.

Comment: @Ranga Nathan did you understand now

Answer (score 3):

This is because week 53 does not necessarily exist, check [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) to learn more about ISO week, in particular, in your case:
"Week 1 is the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January"

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] dates = new String[] { "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", //
        "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY" };
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Integer.parseInt(year), 
        Integer.parseInt(month) - 1, 
        Integer.parseInt(day));
int date_of_week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
return dates[date_of_week - 1];
```

Comment: add some description too